# There are 100 anchor tags in my html page with class 'nav-link', I want to hide first 95 and show only last 5 after page load

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, show-hide

There are 100 anchor tags in my html page with class 'nav-link', I want to hide first  95 anchors tags and only show last five, How can do this in javascript after page load.

For example

```
<a href='#' class="nav-link">Lab Report</a> 
<a href='#' class="nav-link">Pathology Report</a>
<a href='#' class="nav-link">Radiology Report</a>
.
.
.
<a href='#' class="nav-link">Pathology Report</a>
```

I am currently using this code with chrome scripty extension

```
const navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');

// Loop through all the anchor tags
for (let i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
  // Hide all the anchors except the last 5
  if (i < navLinks.length - 5) {
    navLinks[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

but want to check more easy way to do that. I am actually working on a website with very long sidebar and I am using scripty extension to add script so that I do not have to scroll the bar everytime I refresh the page.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: I am using scripty chrome extension to do that so that make my development work easier. I want to find out more easier script.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-link').forEach((e,i)=>{e.style.display=i<95?'none':e.style.display})`

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've got? Other than displaying the last 15 instead of last 5 that is

Comment: yes, I corrected that. I meant last nth if I want to show it as per the requirements

Comment: `i < navLinks.length - 5` in for loop and remove the if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convert the NodeList to an array
2. Use `.slice()` to extract all but the last 5
3. Iterate the remainder and set styles

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link"))
  .slice(0, -5)
  .forEach((link) => (link.style.display = "none"));
```